# CASE statement with list of WHEN values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Tried all sorts of combinations along the lines of SQL snytax but am struggling
I would like to list multiple conditions in a single CASE statement in Cypher along the lines of below

CASE
  WHEN Value1, Value2, Value3 THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END

Is this in fact possible in Cypher, many thanks

Comment: Do you mean combine multiple expressions in a single WHEN clause?  Then I would think you could use logical `OR` between Value1, Value2, Value3... not sure what you’re actually after here for the criteria expression... or is this a collection you want to evaluate against?

Comment: And I think you need to mention the entity for which you're comparing the values 
`CASE WHEN Column_A in (Value1, Value2, Value3) THEN 1 
 ELSE 0 
END`

Comment: Even SQL does not support `WHEN Value1, Value2, Value3`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: seems as though we can use the ColumnA IN [value1, value2, value3], but without square brackets.  many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AND` / `OR` logical operations in a `CASE` statement:

```
MATCH (a:Person)
RETURN 
CASE 
    WHEN a.name="Bob" OR a.name="Bobby" THEN "Robert"
    WHEN a.name="John" AND a.age < 25 THEN "John Jr."
    ELSE "Unknown" 
END AS name
```

Comment: thanks so much, this works a treat.  
seems we can also use   a.name  IN [a, b, c, d]

Comment: Yeah, any boolean expression should be valid between `WHEN` and `THEN`